# resolvable function

Tags: functions

I need help.
Show that the system of equations:
$$y_1 + \cos(y_1y_2) = y_2x_1 + 1$$ 
$$\sin(y_1) = x_2 + y_2$$
in an environment of $(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)=(0, −1, 0, 1)$ , 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\y_2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
f_1(x_1,x_2)\\f_2(x_1,x_2)
\end{pmatrix}$$

can be resolved, and calculate $f'(0, -1)$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the neighborhood of $(y_1,y_2):=(0,1)$ we can solve the given system for $(x_1,x_2)$ by inspection:
$$x_1={y_1+\cos(y_1y_2)-1\over y_2}\ ,\qquad x_2=\sin y_1-y_2\ .\tag{1}$$
The equations $(1)$ define a function
$\Phi:\>(y_1,y_2)\mapsto (x_1,x_2)$ with $\Phi(0,1)=(0,-1)$. The $f$ in your problem is the inverse of $\Phi$, which is defined in a neighborhood of $(0,-1)$. There is an essential "technical assumption" for the existence of this $f$, namely that $${\rm det}\bigl(d\Phi(0,1)\bigr)\ne0\ .$$
Therefore you have to compute the matrix $[d\Phi(0,1)]$. If its determinant is $\ne0$ you can proceed and declare that $df(0,-1)=\bigl(d\Phi(0,1)\bigr)^{-1}$, as maps and as matrices.